# OpenGL why deselect shader program?

Tags: opengl, shader, opengl-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is glDisableClientState required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773010/is-gldisableclientstate-required)

In OpenGL I've seen this code which follows this pattern quite often:

```
glUseProgram(prog_id);
// ... do some stuff
glUseProgram(0);
```

I understand that `glUseProgram(0)` deselects any shader programs. Now my question is what does it mean to deselect a shader program?

For example, why should or shouldn't I do something like this in a render loop?

```
while(render_loop_condition)
{
    glUseProgram(prog_id);
    // do some stuff
}
// various cleanup code
glUseProgram(0);
```

What about in a render loop which uses multiple shader programs, can I do something like this:

```
while(render_loop_condition)
{
    glUseProgram(prog_id1);
    // do some stuff
    glUseProgram(prog_id2);
    // do some other stuff
}
// various cleanup code
glUseProgram(0);
```

Comment: `glUseProgram(0)` doesn't deselect the shader program. According to the OpenGL spec the results are `undefined` (http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUseProgram.xml)

Comment: In a way, it does. glUseProgram(0) selects an invalid program. This is a similar concept to setting pointers to null once you're done with them. Only the execution of the invalid program results in undefined behavior, but you can use glGet(GL_CURRENT_PROGRAM) to determine what the current shader program is, or 0 if none. The statement is there to clarify that handling of what to do if no shader program is currently selected should not rely on some error/exception being raised on invalid program execution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's used to avoid any unintended side effects on what's drawn afterwards. It's perfectly fine (and in my opinion, preferable) to switch between programs within a method, but to select the default program (`0`) at the end of the method. That way you won't encounter any strange side-effects after calling that method.

There aren't a whole lot of side-effects that I can think of, but I guess if you're drawing something the fixed-function way, you would accidentally draw with the last program you bound.

And just a note, with the second block of code you posted, you can move the first `glUseProgram` call outside of the while loop to prevent binding the same program multiple times.